# Optional params in javascript route - how to indicate None

Tags: scala, playframework

I have an Action with optional params that looks like this:

```
def editLink(storyId: Long, linkId: Long, thumbnail: Option[String], title: Option[String], description: Option[String], hidden: Option[Boolean]) = Action.async { ... }
```

This action is exposed as a JSRoute. I had assumed that providing `null` as a param to the javascript route from JavaScript would map to Scala's `None`, but that appears to be incorrect and, instead, it translates to a literal `"null"` String. How can I indicate that certain query parameters are `None` when using this action from JavaScript?

Comment: I know nothing about Play, but the most natural equivalent would be `undefined`, or not precising the value of the parameter at all. For example, `editLink(17, 18, "thumbnail")`

Comment: @Dici undefined makes sense. I'll try that. If it works, you can post that as an answer. I'll let you know, thanks.

Comment: @Dici this works by the way. Leave it as an answer? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I posted n answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript, this wonderful language has two keywords usually used to define the absence of something. `null` is one of them, `undefined` is another one. Knowing that when you omit a parameter in a function, it gets passed as `undefined`, I would imagine that this is what you should use for an optional parameter. As an example :

```
var f = function (param, optionalParam) {
   console.log(optionalParam);
}

f(1, 2); // prints 2
f(1); // prints undefined
```